# Is there any way to turn regular ranged weapon attacks into Touch attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, touch-attacks

Just this basic question.  Any feat, skill trick, spell, regardless of source would be fine, just want to know if i've missed something or if the means doesn't actually exist to do so.

The only way i've found is Bloodstorm Blade to make your thrown weapon attack count as melee, and then something like wraithstrike or find the gap to make it into a touch attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5 levels in the Master Thrower prestige class gives you choice to use Weak Spot trick. It allows make range touch attacks instead of normal range attacks, but you loses `Str` modifier for them

Comment: Combined with Aptitude, this does what I want.  Excellent.  5 levels is definitely a painful investment, but what ho, onwards.

Answer (score 4):

The [Fell Shot](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicFeats.htm#fellShot) psionic feat turns a ranged attack into a ranged touch attack with the expenditure of the character's psionic focus.

Comment: Useful, but not really applicable to full attacks, which is mostly what i'm looking at.  Definitely the sort of thing a Manyshot archer might be looking at.